# Form tags not generated when two forms on one page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, modal-dialog

I know this is stupid question but I tried everything I could think of ( except AJAX ).

I have two forms on one page:  one is for registration and the other is for report.

Form for report is in modal popup(bootstrap).

When I remove one form(doesn't matter which one it works perfectly). But when both forms are present Form tag for report is not generated. I get CSRF token for another form but I am not getting form tag. The result for this is that i get mixed POST request with some information from one and some from another form.

I double checked if everything is closed properly. Maybe I am tired and I can't see the problem.

Can someone help me with this issue ?

EDIT:
Registration form

```
<?= Form::open(array('url' => route('expert.store'), 'files' => true, 'method'=>'post', 'id' =>'super')); ?>
<div class="title">
    Apply for Account
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
            Email
            <?= Form::email('email','', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            First name:
            <?= Form::text('first_name','', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
        <div >
            Last name:
            <?= Form::text('last_name','' , array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            Password:
            <?= Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            Confirm password:
            <?= Form::password('confirm_password',array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="buttons">

    <?= Form::submit('Apply', array('class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block'))?>
</div>
<?php  Form::Close(); ?>
```

Modal popup:

```
<div class="modal" id="discrimination" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="close-button" data-dismiss="modal">
    X
</div>
<div class="modal-popup" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:480px">
    <div class="form-holder">
        <?= Form::open(array('url' => '/postNewReport', 'files' => true, 'id'=>'dernek')); ?>
        <div class="reporting-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <?= Form::text('first_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control short-field')); ?>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <?= Form::text('last_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control short-field')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div >
                    <?= Form::textarea('report_text', '', array('class' => 'form-control long-field')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div >
                    <?= Form::text('email','' ,array('class' =>'form-control short-field')) ?>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send">

            </input>
            <div class="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                Cancel
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php  Form::Close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code. Impossible to know from just reading the description here!

Comment: ah, sry :) updated in a minute

Comment: You should post generated html which you can find using view-source option in browser.

Comment: Are you missing a closing `</div>` on the modal?

Comment: No,I checked that.
@ApulGupta, sry I went to sleep. I found solution, thnx for your help.
I will update question.

Comment: its a stupid question till it happens to you . Lol thanks for asking this saved me hours today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was missing for those forms are names, after I added name tag for both form everything was working fine.

Before that I tried with ids but that didn't work out.

Form tags now:
Report:

```
<?= Form::open(array('url' => '/postNewReport', 'files' => true, 'name'=>'newReport')); ?>
```

Registration:

```
<?= Form::open(array('url' => route('expert.store'), 'files' => true, 'method'=>'post', 'name'=>'expertForm')); ?>
```